# How can I call an ipcMain command from another ipcMain command?

Tags: node.js, electron

Unfortunately I am brand new to electron, in efforts to be DRY I need to kick off `loadFolders` from inside `makeFolder`, `loadFolders` will trigger an event for ipcRenderer to load my updated folder names

All examples online are shown sending a message from ipcMain to ipcRenderer but never from one backend function to another, is this even possible?

```
ipcMain.on('loadFolders', (e, args) => {
  // ...
  // does some stuff to read folder names from the file system
  // ...
  // sends folder list to the view
  mainWindow.webContents.send('folderItems', items)
})

ipcMain.on('makeFolder', (e, args) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      // ...
      // creates a folder from args
      // ** need to call the loadFolders method here in order to read
      // updated list from the filesystem **
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: turn `loadFolders` into a function (rather than using `ipcMain`) and just call it from within `makeFolder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In electron, you have only ONE main process(like a server) and multiple renderer processes (like tabs in the browser).

IPC stands for inter-process communication. But there isn't any need for IPC in the main process. You can use regular function calls for example.

But if you need to "talk" to renderer processes from the main process or vice versa or between renderer processes then use ipcMain() and ipcRender() respectively.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain it is something you should do, as other have pointed out.
Having said that, you absolutely can!
You can emit an event from your main process and catch it on your main process aswell.

e.g.: In your main process:

```
ipcMain.on('doSomething', ()=>{console.log('I did something!')});
ipcMain.emit('doSomething');
```

this will output 'I did something!' on your console.